# Octave plotting weirdly

Tags: plot, octave

I am trying to use Octave to plot a quadratic equation by substituting a, b, c, and x into the quadratic equation.
Here is my code:

```
a = 1; b = 6; c = 9; %values of a, b, and c in a quadratic equation

root1 = -(-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a); %finds first root with +
root2 = -(-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a); %finds second root with -

disp("1st root: "); disp(root1); disp("2nd root: "); disp(root2); 

v = (root1 + root2) / 2; %finds vertex x coord
quadratic_eqn = @(a, b, c, x) a*x^2 + b*x + c;

xvec = [v - 20; v - 10; v; v + 10; v + 20]
hold on;
plot(xvec(1), quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec(1)));

plot(xvec(2), quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec(2)));

plot(xvec(3), quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec(3)));

plot(xvec(4), quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec(4)));

plot(xvec(5), quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec(5)));
```

It finds the root and vertex fine, but when actually plotting, it returns whatever this is: [image]

How do I make it plot the points that I want it to?

Comment: You don't create a new figure or clear the existing figure in your script, so this might be different plots overlaid. When I run your code I see 5 dots.

Comment: You should define your anonymous function as `@(a, b, c, x) a*x.^2 + b*x + c` (note the dot in front of the power operator), then the function is vectorized. You can now do a single plot command: `plot(xvec, quadratic_eqn(a, b, c, xvec), 'o')`. And then you can define your `xvec` more densely too: `xvec=linspace(v-20,v+20,100);`.

Comment: what Cris said, plus, you have `hold on` without a `hold off` at the end, which means the `hold on` effect stays active between subsequent runs of this script.